# What's the story behind the making of the Complutensian Polyglot Bible?

Tags: spain, 15th-century, bible

[The Complutensian Polyglot Bible was the first printed polyglot of the entire Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complutensian_Polyglot_Bible) and was, from what I can gather, a pretty complex scholarly effort in which many different scholars had to come together in Alcalá de Henares (or Complutum in Latin) and needed to work for 15 years. This all had to be financed, the scholars had to work together, the produced manuscripts needed to be printed and so on. This immense scholarly research project, maybe the first of its kind after the invention of the printing press, probably needed a lot of organisational effort.

I was wondering if it is known how this early project of biblical philology was practically carried out. I'm basically interested in "scholarship in the making" with this one, if that makes sense.

- How did the scholars work?
- Where exactly did they meet?
- Who was in charge?
- What technologies besides the printing press were used?
- How did they keep track of their efforts?

Comment: It seems to have been entirely financed by (Spanish) [Cardinal Francisco Cisneros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Jim%C3%A9nez_de_Cisneros). He also personally financed at least one attack on Morrocco. Cardinal back then must have been a pretty sweet gig.

Comment: Some of this is provided in the Wikipedia artical: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complutensian_Polyglot_Bible); the two books listed as "Further Reading" should provide answers, esp. Lyell, James P. R. (1917), Cardinal Ximenes, Statesman, Ecclesiastic, Soldier, and Man of Letters: with an Account of the Complutensian Polyglot Bible. London: Coptic House, 1917.